# ECCODES ERROR when opening .GRIB file in Spyder

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, grib, eccodes

I have accessed Anaconda Prompt for the environment that I will be working.

Once there, I have changed the directory to the place where I have the grib files that I will be working with, in order to install cfgrib, I have used the following command:

`conda install -c conda-forge cfgrib`

As the Python module depends on ECMWF ecCodes binary library, in the same Anaconda Prompt, I ran the following command:

`conda install -c conda-forge eccodes`

Then, opened the file in Spyder, and tried to run this simple script:

```
import xarray as xr

ds = xr.open_dataset('download.grib', engine='cfgrib')
ds
```

But got the following error:

> Can't read index file 'C:\Users\name\Desktop\data\download.grib.90c91.idx'
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\name\anaconda3\envs\Weather\lib\site-packages\cfgrib\messages.py", line 351, in from_indexpath_or_filestream
> self = cls.from_indexpath(indexpath)
> File "C:\Users\name\anaconda3\envs\Weather\lib\site-packages\cfgrib\messages.py", line 323, in from_indexpath
> return pickle.load(file)
> EOFError: Ran out of input

Then,

> An error ocurred while starting the kernel
> ECCODES ERROR : Unable to find boot.def. Context path=D:/bld/eccodes_1593015095851/_h_env/Library/share/eccodes/definitions
>
> Possible causes:
> ‑ The software is not correctly installed
> ‑ The environment variable ECCODES_DEFINITION_PATH is defined but incorrect ecCodes assertion failed: `0' in D:\bld\eccodes_1593015095851\work\src\grib_context.c:226

[image: Error starting the kernel]

What am I missing here?

---

**Edit 1**

The problem also happens if I use Visual Studio Code.

In the terminal, if I am inside the directory that the GRIB files are stored, and I activate the environment that I am working with:

```
conda activate Weather
```

And then:

```
& C:/Users/name/anaconda3/envs/Weather/python.exe c:/Users/name/Desktop/data/3_climate/2mtemp_open.py
```

It gives the same error as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, `ECCODES_DEFINITION_PATH` was not set.

As I am using Anaconda on Windows 10, the path is the following

```
C:/Users/[USER]/Anaconda3/envs/envgeo/Library/share/eccodes/definitions
```

In order to set the environment variable, one can simply run

```
setx ECCODES_DEFINITION_PATH "[ECCODES definition path/directory]"
```

This should solve the problem.

However, a new one may emerge. As the .grib file may take a lot to run, consider using the data in the format NetCDF.